# Endorsing Policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger Fabric endorsement policy is specified at chaincode instatiation using -P .

Is there any way other than specifying using CLI writing endorsement policy in a file and link that file at chaincode instantiation time instead of using cli?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install chaincode via one of the Hyperledger [Fabric SDKs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/getting_started.html#hyperledger-fabric-sdks) and specify the policy as a JSON object. Here's an example from the [Node SDK](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#ChaincodeInstantiateUpgradeRequest):

Endorsement policy: "Signed by any member from one of the organizations"

```
{
  identities: [
    { role: { name: "member", mspId: "org1" }},
    { role: { name: "member", mspId: "org2" }}
  ],
  policy: {
    "1-of": [{ "signed-by": 0 }, { "signed-by": 1 }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you christo4ferris

Comment: but where does the data structure sits?

Comment: The JSON above can be embedded in the app code or it can be read from the FS or a database. How you choose to manage is your choice.